# Generate nodejs from Swagger spec

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

So I've documented my whole API with swagger editor, and now I have my .yaml file.  I'm really confused how I take that and generate the whole nodejs stuff now so that all those functions are already defined and then I just fill them in with the appropriate code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) generates server stubs and client SDKs for a variety of languages and frameworks, including Node.js.

To generate a Node.js server stub, run codegen with the `-l nodejs-server` argument.

Windows example:

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2-2-2.jar generate -i petstore.yaml -l nodejs-server -o .\PetstoreServer
```

You get:

```
.
├── api
|    └── swagger.yaml
├── controllers
|    ├── Pet.js
|    ├── PetService.js
|    ├── Store.js
|    ├── StoreService.js
|    ├── User.js
|    └── UserService.js
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── README.md
└── .swagger-codegen-ignore
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great!  Is there a way to generate it using typescript instead of just plain javascript?

Comment: @Gargoyle: There are TypeScript generators too, try `-l typescript-node`.

Comment: That looks like it is generating a client side, not a server side.

Comment: @Gargoyle: My bad. Looks like Swagger Codegen does not have a TypeScript server generator currently. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36681516/113116) mentions the [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) project as a possible alternative. Also check out the [list of Node.js integrations](http://swagger.io/open-source-integrations/#node-js-15) on http://swagger.io.