# Indicate to ReSharper or Visual Studio that JSON variable is instance of Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper

My front-end libraries sometimes require JSON data from my MVC application (e.g. jQGrid). I'm accommodating this when needed by converting the required model classes to JSON. However I'm running into an issue where refactoring such models can occasionally become difficult; neither ReSharper, nor Visual Studio, can identify this "model access" after the model's been converted into JSON-- only when it's used within C# templating (either old-school WebForms or Razor).

Is there any way I can hint to either VS or ReSharper that, for instance, the JS variable `rowObject` used within jQGrid is equivalent to a usage of the C# class `MyModel`? Ideally so I can get things like intellisense, but more importantly, so that ReSharper's "Find Usages" of the class / its properties can identify that it's being used here. (e.g. "Find Usages" of `MyModel.Name` => this usage of `rowObject.Name`)

```
// <Back-End>
public JsonResult JsonList(string userName)
{
    var model = new List<MyModel>()
    ...
    return Json(model.OrderByDescending(x => x.WhenSent), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

// <Front-End>
$("#jQGridExample").jqGrid({
    url: '<%= Url.Action("JsonList", "MyController") %>',
    datatype: "json",
    ...
    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    // rowObject is of type "MyModel" but neither tool will know this.
    // If I remove a property from "MyModel" without updating the JS & rowObject uses it,
    // this can become an easily missed front-end regression.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because there is not only a layer-wise break (front vs. back end), but a technical one as well - namely JS vs. C#. As long as there is no direct bridge between C# and JS on a compiler/R# level, this will remain impossible.

Of course you can mitigate those issues by creating models in JS/TypeScript that are *similar* to their C# pendants (meaning same names, properties, etc.) - e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70515122/share-models-between-c-sharp-and-typescript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693335/how-to-generate-basic-typescript-interfaces-from-swagger-schema). But they are not *technically the same*.

Comment: The automatic typescript conversion is interesting, I'd seen it before but had forgotten it. It could achieve a similar result to what I'm after, as an attribute on the C# model marking it for conversion to TS signifies at least that "there's 2 places to look" & type-checking in TS would nip refactoring bugs in the bud before runtime. If integrating TS ends up difficult though, looks like I'm left facing some kind of "code-gen" to enable associating C# & JS usages. Thanks for the input.